# Server giving 404 not found

Tags: http-status-code-404, cloud-foundry

I am deploying a spring application which contains files with around 100000 entries. Each row in the file has about 23 chars. 
The app deploys fine when a file has 100000 entries but when I increase the contents to 400000 entries, when I access my app url I get a 404 Not found error.

I need to figure out what causes the crash ( whether a memory problem or something else ) but I do not see anything erroneous in the tomcat log files, using the command vmc files [app_name] tomcat/logs/catalina.... just info messages related to server startup.

Are there other options to debug the issue?

Thanks,
Cristian

Comment: When you redeploy the application does VMC say it was "Staged" and "Started" OK? or is this where it crashes?

Comment: Hi Dan, the vmc apps command shows me that after I redeploy the app, my application has Health = 0%.Also, I noticed from the spring deployer in eclipse that at first the app is shown as starting, the stopped and then finally started.

Comment: Hi Christian, I think the most likely cause of this issue is resource limitations on CloudFoundry.com, especially if the application is loading all the data when it starts up. If you feel this is not the case I will happily stage a copy of the application myself and take a look.

Comment: Hi, I know that there is a 2 GB memory limit. Is this correct? The difference in MB between the 100000 entries file and the 400000 entries one is roughly 8 MB, so I was thinking that memory could not be such a big issue. Can you please stage the app and tell me what you find? I should first get the app with the 400000 entries file up on cloudfoundry. I'll let you know when I do that. Thanks,Cristian

Comment: Hi Christian, can you send an archived copy of the application to support@cloudfoundry.com if it is not too large.

Comment: Hi Dan. It seems that the file is too big ( 20 MB ) for the cloudfoundry mail servers. Is there another way I can give it to you?

Comment: Sure, do you use Google Drive, Dropbox or similar?

Comment: It's up on Google Drive. What email address should I use to share the file to you?

Comment: Hi Dan. I tried with as few as 120000 entries in the file and now I get intermittent 404 and 502 while trying to access different pages. I used the Java apis to find out how much memory is allocated and how much is used. It's around 190MB used out of a total of 490MB.

Comment: Hi Christian, my gmail address is dan.higham@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the application was using too much memory, as a result the Java processes was being destroyed causing the router to return a 404 when trying to route to the application.

Comment: Hi Dan. That was the problem. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into what Dan has mentioned! Also can you look at the logs folder to see if the files there give more information.

```
vmc logs <app-name>
```

or

```
vmc files <app-name> logs/stderr.log
vmc files <app-name> logs/stdout.log
```

Comment: Nothing relevant in those logs either. Just some INFO logs about catalina startup.